# Big data architecture for industry (sensor data )

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, bigdata, apache-kafka

A new project came to my hands and looks interesting for my own. 
I need to stored all the coming data from industrial PLCs (control the machinery inside a factory) and every event in the plc generated a output that need to be saved for after data analysis.
I was wondering what will be the perfect match for this type of data (time series) to make a hole architecture to manage data IO and at the moment only querying it for graphics (later will be applied machine learning analysis for predictive maintenance).

I don't know if I working in the correct direction and will be good to have some knowledge from experts in that subject.

1. **IO producer** (this a own made project and cant not be change)
2. **IO events layer** --> Is apache kafka a option for manage a big amount of signal coming for a lot of different computers (collected to plcs) and also manage the data saving to a nosql database. (it is suitable for that?any better option)
3. **nosql database**--> This point is more clear choosing Cassandra for time series storing.
4. **queryng nosql data**--> We are choosing spark for make fast queries and later on some data analysis.

The layer where I have more doubts is the layer involved in administrate the io data before storing and I have serious doubts that kafka is the correct option.

Thanks for reading and sorry for my bad English ;) Feel free to give your point of view.

Comment: Hi! Stack Overflow is not a great place for such design discussions. More focused, non-subjective technical questions have a better chance of getting good answers here. For a design question like this, I'd suggest the user mailing lists of the mentioned projects. Specifically users@kafka.apache.org.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, the problem if you ask directly to a determinate project forum the question many times will be "it the best option you have to do it" for that I prefered to ask in a more agnostic forum. But thanks for reply me

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that. Another idea is you could try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get a good response here.

Answer (score 0):

we have a similar project based on sensor data. we have about 30 GB of data coming per day. We use kafka to stream the data and store it in hdfs. we have a set up of python ( numpy , pandas and pyspark) along with spark for any data crunching basically for prediction part. 
As far as your doubts on kafka goes ... its capable enuf to handle large datasets. The other benfit would be that kafka can handle multiple sources and will be easier to scale. 
As far as data storage is concerned i would recommend you to go with HDFS as it can be used in multiple ways to consume the data. You can leverage hive or hbase if required in future.